# Command failed: wmic os get Caption

Tags: sharepoint, yeoman, sharepoint-online, yeoman-generator, spfx

I have an issue when run this command for spfx yo @microsoft/sharepoint

i try to use spfx to create web part and upload it to sharepoint online (modern site)

I use Win 8.1
@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.4.1

```
λ yo @microsoft/sharepoint
C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
throw err;
^
Error: Command failed: wmic os get Caption
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"
    at makeError (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:34:24)
    at osName (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:54:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)"
```

[image: See image]

[image: See image]

Comment: having the same issue. I get the same error if I just run "yo" without any parameters.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) the **System** environment variable `Path` and add `c:\Windows\System32\wbem;`  Make sure to close and reopen any command line window for the change to take effect.

Comment: This solved my issue. Was trying to create a React Office Addin and yo wasn't working until i did this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by resetting the machine. This was happening on a dev VM that spends most of its time suspended so it hadn't been restarted in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you are using SPFx 1.4.1 ?

You can try using latest version of SharePoint Framework like 1.8 or 1.9.1.

Follow below steps to resolve the issue:

1. If you already node installed the uninstall it and remove everything related to Node JS from "C:\Program Files".
2. Download latest version of Node JS from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
3. Install gulp and yeoman generator using command: `npm install -g yo gulp`
4. Install SPFx generator using command: `npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`
5. Then try to create new webpart using: `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`

Check an article for more information: [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment).